# React: Properties change to undefined after updating a property in an array of objects

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

What I was trying to do is just updating a property in an object in an array and update the array state.
But all the properties change to `undefined` except for the one that has been updated after updating the object.

Code is like below.

```
    let copyOfItems = [...items];
    console.log(copyOfItems[currentIndex].propertyA);  // a Value
    const updatedItem = {
      ...copyOfItems[currentIndex],
      propertyB: "newVal"
    };
    console.log(updatedItem.propertyA);  // undefined
    console.log(updatedItem.propertyB);  // newVal
    copyOfItems[currentIndex] = updatedItem;
    setItems(copyOfItems);
```

What is wrong with this?

Comment: The code as shown will work, so there's something else going on somewhere. Please update your question with a [mcve] demonstrating the problem, ideally a **runnable** one using Stack Snippets (the `[<>]` toolbar button). Stack Snippets support React, including JSX; [here's how to do one](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/338537/).

Comment: (`setItem` seems an odd name for something being used to set `items`. Did you mean `setItems`?)

Comment: [Works for me](https://codesandbox.io/s/so-question-68881248-5xcw0).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not try it this way to see how it works?

```
let copyOfItems = [...items];
    console.log(copyOfItems[currentIndex].propertyA);  // a Value
    copyOfItems[currentIndex]['propertyB'] = 'new val'; // yes this is valid
    console.log(copyOfItems[currentIndex].propertyA);  // this should not be undefined
    console.log(copyOfItems[currentIndex].propertyB);  // newVal
    setItems(copyOfItems);
```

Comment: I actually tried this way and yes it actually updated the array and the object in the array properly but there is a weird thing happening in this way. I pass this array to a child component and `useEffect` to this array's change stopped working in this way. I will update the question.

Comment: Yes it might not work because there was no object change, so before passing it to the child's component, make sure you make a new copy of it like so: <component array={[...thisarray]}/> that will force a change on the array.

Comment: Ah I see.. Yes it actually works when I pass the copy to the child component. But what does object change mean exactly? I don't understand this concept well to be honest. This way also assign a new value to the property of the object in the array, right? Doesn't it mean object change?

Comment: React does a shallow comparison to see if there are changes within the states, as such, it keeps reference to all the existing states and objects (arrays, objects, declarations etc.). So, if you pass the same object even if there are properties changes, it will assume that it is the same object, and thus no re-render will happen. However if you make a new copy, since reference to the new copy does not exists, it will assume  that a true change has occurred, and therefore re-render.

Comment: Hmm, but both my and your ways create a copy of the array (`copyOfItems`) and use `setItems`, right? Doesn't your way make a new reference to the array? Why doesn't your way work unless I make a new copy of the array again when passing it to child? Sorry it might be really basic question.

Comment: Because we are making reference to the same array, only changing the property.  So, for it to be considered a true change, you have to specifically create a new array and spread the former, thus forcing react to recognize it as a new object altogether.